# Need help to create a Photo sharing Windows Universal app, which API should I use to change photo's effect

Tags: photo, uwp

I need to create a UWP app like Instagram, so I have to find a way to change Photo's effect easily, does anyone have recommended library to make it works in UWP? Should I use the underlying API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lumia Imaging SDK** should be what you need, it gives us access to a powerful library of exciting image-manipulation tools for Windows and Windows Phone devices. Designed from the ground up with performance and a low-memory footprint in mind, the Imaging SDK 3.0 makes editing high-resolution images swift and engaging. See this page: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/featured/lumia

Imaging SDK documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt598502.aspx

The Sample projects can be found in Lumia Imaging SDK Git repository: https://github.com/Microsoft/Lumia-Imaging-SDK#samples

Comment: Thank you! I've seen the sample, absolutely what I need!!